# How to assign a Jira issue with C#?

Tags: c#, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using the [Atlassian.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Atlassian.SDK/) NuGet package for automating Jira and I'm facing an issue that the Assignee property's set method isn't working:

```
Jira jira = new Jira(JiraSettings.API_Url, JiraSettings.API_User, JiraSettings.API_Password);

Issue issue = jira.CreateIssue(Project);
issue.Type = IssueTypes.Task;
issue.Summary = ticketSubject;
issue.Description = ticketBody;
issue.Priority = priority;
issue.Assignee = JiraSettings.DefaultAssignee;

issue.SaveChanges();
```

This code opens a new issue but the assignee isn't the one I chose, so I downloaded the [Atlassian.SDK](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/downloads) repository and debugged it. It turns out the request that is sent includes the correct assignee but the response is with the user I'm logged in with (`JiraSettings.API_User`).

**Q:** Does anyone know of a way to workaround this issue or fix it perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure that project has a default assignee? It's normal to be empty is there is no one assigned as default.

Comment: Yes, there is a default assignee defined for that project in Jira.